# 60Gb missing after deleting Bootcamp partition

Tags: macos, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I recently uninstalled Bootcamp on my MacbookPro 256gb.I had granted 60Gb to Windows but unfortunately, I can't recover those gigs in my main Apple container.

I [tried to find solutions for this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/420715/5472), but not [having quite the same structure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/207248/5472) as me, I didn't want to make mistakes.

Here is a screenshot of my "diskutil list”

[image]

I know I have to do a command to delete one of its partitions but which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you are using Big Sur. If so, then partition with the identifier `disk0s3` is not needed. To remove this partition and recover the free space, enter the commands given below.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: Boy, oh, boy, do I want to hug you for this!