# Recover deleted partition space

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, partition, disk-space, core-storage

I am having the exact same issue when it comes to not being able to reclaim space as in the answered question below...

[Reclaim hard drive space from deleted partition and reclaim Apple bootloader](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186743/reclaim-hard-drive-space-from-deleted-partition-and-reclaim-apple-bootloader)

I went into terminal and compared my data to the solved and could not figure out which index I need to be focused on while in recovery mode.  And is there a way I can send a message or ask a question to a specific person on this site such as the person who had solved the above issue?  Please any help is really appreciated! Some Terminal info is below.

[image: terminal info]

Comment: The problem here is a little bit different compared to the linked question: 1. you have two Recovery HDs and 2. your main volume is a CoreStorage stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though similar to the linked question your partition table has some specific differences: you have a second Recovery HD with a false partition type and your main volume is part of a CoreStorage stack.

First you have to determine the proper system versions of the Recovery HDs and then remove the older or - if identical - remove the one with the wrong partition type (disk0s4). After removing one of the Recovery HDs you have to resize the CoreStorage stack:

**Preparation:**

- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.

  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan) or a thumb drive containing a full system (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan). If you boot to a full system and login as admin you have to prepend `sudo` to execute some commands like `gpt ...` or `newfs_hfs ...`!

**Check system versions of Recovery HDs**

- Open in the menubar Utlities->Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` to get an overview
- Get the product version of the visible Recovery HD:

  ```
  grep ProductVersion -A 1 /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/SystemVersion.plist
  ```

  depending on the main system version it should yield something like:

  ```
  <key>ProductVersion</key>
  <string>10.11.5</string>
  ```
- Unmount disk0s4:

  ```
  diskutil unmount disk0s4
  ```
- Mount the hidden Recovery HD partition:

  ```
  diskutil mount disk0s3
  ```
- Check that only one Recovery HD (disk0s3) is mounted:

  ```
  df
  ```
- Get the product version of the invisible Recovery HD:

  ```
  grep ProductVersion -A 1 /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/SystemVersion.plist
  ```

  depending on the main system version it should yield something like:

  ```
  <key>ProductVersion</key>
  <string>10.11.5</string>
  ```
- If the product version of the visible is the same or older than the one of the invisible Recovery HD delete the visible Recovery HD partition:

  ```
  diskutil list
  diskutil umount diskX #Unmount the logical volume residing on disk0s2 with X: 1...~16 (e.g. disk1) like shown in the previous command
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 4 disk0
  ```
- Get the UUID of the logical volume:

  ```
  diskutil cs list
  ```
- Resize the CoreStorage stack to fill the whole disk:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID 0 #lvUUID: UUID of the logical volume
  ```

  The 0 (zero) as magical size sometimes fails. Then use a size ~1g smaller than your disk size (i.e. 250g or 249700m).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40737/discussion-on-answer-by-klanomath-recover-deleted-partition-space).